# Java AST form annotation from String

Tags: java, annotations, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to create annotations from inner string which contains other annotations.

This is SimpleAnnotation that should be processed:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface SimpleAnnotation {
    String[] value() default {};
}
```

This is annotated class

```
@SimpleAnnotation({
                   "@com.demo.annotations.Entity(name = \"simple_name\")", 
                   "@com.demo.annotations.CustomAnnotation"
                 })
public class Simple {
}
```

The compilation result of annotated class should be

```
@com.demo.annotations.Entity(name = "simple_name")
@com.demo.annotations.CustomAnnotation                     
public class Simple {
}
```

I've tried to use custom annotation processor 
that processes class declaration. It gets class modifiers with annotations and analyzes derived annotation as tree

```
    public class SimpleAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        private Messager messager;

        private Trees trees;
        private ChangeTranslator visitor;

        @Override
        public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
            return Collections.singleton(SimpleAnnotation.class.getCanonicalName());
        }

        @Override
        public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
            return SourceVersion.RELEASE_8;
        }


        @Override
        public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        ............
        }

        @Override
        public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
            Set<? extends Element> elementsAnnotatedWith = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(SimpleAnnotation.class);

            for (Element element : elementsAnnotatedWith) {
                Name simpleName = element.getSimpleName();
                System.out.println(simpleName);
                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "found with annotation " + simpleName);

                JCTree tree = (JCTree) trees.getTree(element);

                visitor.setElement(element);

                tree.accept(visitor);
            }

            return true;
        }


       public class ChangeTranslator extends TreeTranslator {

        private JavacProcessingEnvironment javacProcessingEnvironment;
        private TreeMaker treeMaker;
        private Messager messager;

        public ChangeTranslator(JavacProcessingEnvironment javacProcessingEnvironment, TreeMaker treeMaker, Messager messager) {
            this.javacProcessingEnvironment = javacProcessingEnvironment;
            this.treeMaker = treeMaker;
            this.messager = messager;
        }    

        @Override
        public void visitClassDef(JCTree.JCClassDecl jcClassDecl) {
            super.visitClassDef(jcClassDecl);

            if (isNeedProcessing(jcClassDecl)) {

                JCTree.JCModifiers modifiers = jcClassDecl.getModifiers();

                List<JCTree.JCAnnotation> annotations = modifiers.getAnnotations();

                List<JCTree.JCAnnotation> jcAnnotations = List.nil();

                for (JCTree.JCAnnotation a : annotations) {
                    if (a.getAnnotationType().toString().contains(SimpleAnnotation.class.getSimpleName())) {                           
                        List<JCTree.JCExpression> arguments = a.getArguments();

                        for (JCTree.JCExpression arg : arguments) {

                            JCTree.JCNewArray expressions = (JCTree.JCNewArray) ((JCTree.JCAssign) arg).getExpression();
                            List<JCTree.JCExpression> elems = expressions.elems;
                            for (JCTree.JCExpression expression : elems) {                                    


                               // parse annotation from string
                               String value = (String) ((JCTree.JCLiteral) expression).getValue();

                          // e.g com.demo.annotations.Entity
                          String substringName = value.trim().substring(1, 28);
                                Class<? extends Class> aClass = null;

                                try {
                                    aClass = Class.forName(substringName);                                      

                                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }



                                // 1 - attribute to create annotation from 
                                Attribute attribute = new Attribute.Compound(aClass, null);

                                // 2 - place where annotation should be created
                                treeMaker.Annotation(attribute);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                modifiers.annotations = jcAnnotations;

                System.out.println(result);
            }

        }

        private boolean isNeedProcessing(JCTree.JCClassDecl jcClassDecl) {
            return jcClassDecl.getModifiers().toString().contains("@SimpleAnnotation");
        }

    }
}
```

**The issue is to get information from Class type to create com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.ClassType which is used to create JCAnnotation.**

*Any help is appreciated.*

Comment: Why you have such requirement? If you are not develop some library like lombok, it is possible a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Dean Xu 
I have shared library with models. In one project model has to be annotated but in another it doesn't have to be annotated. In order not to duplicate models in another project custom annotation processor was created. The purpose of this processor to inject necessary annotations to class declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public class SimpleAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    ...
    @Override
    public void visitClassDef(JCTree.JCClassDecl jcClassDecl) {
        ...
        ListBuffer<JCTree.JCExpression> params = new ListBuffer<JCTree.JCExpression>();
        params.append(treeMaker.Assign(treeMaker.Ident(names.fromString("name")), treeMaker.Literal("simple_name")));
        JCTree.JCAnnotation entity = treeMaker.Annotation(select("com.demo.annotations.Entity"), params.toList());
        JCTree.JCAnnotation customAnnotation = treeMaker.Annotation(select("com.demo.annotations.CustomAnnotation"), List.nil());
        // then append annotation to modifiers of you want
        // NOTE: List<A>.append() method will return a new List in javac
        ...
    }

    JCTree.JCExpression select(String path) {
        JCTree.JCExpression expression = null;
        int i = 0;
        for (String split : path.split("\\.")) {
            if (i == 0)
                expression = treeMaker.Ident(names.fromString(split));
            else {
                expression = treeMaker.Select(expression, names.fromString(split));
            }
            i++;
        }

        return expression;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps those who have the same problem